Potential energy has been created from no energy
Suppose there are two identical metal plates separated by a certain distance, and a small ball with static electricity is fixed at the midpoint of this distance. For the electric field of the small ball, the two metal plates are located on the equipotential surface.
Now use a battery to charge the two metal plates, and an electric field is generated between the metal plates, and the charged small ball gains electric potential energy.
In this scenario, there is no other object that transfers kinetic energy to the ball, and the ball itself has no energy that can be converted into electric potential energy. The battery's electrical energy is stored in the metal plate. The ball has no effect on the external environment because everything is located on the equipotential surface of the ball's electric field.
The questions I will pose are as follows：
What energy do you think is converted into the potential energy of the ball?
How does physics describe this way of obtaining energy?
Do you think energy is still conserved here?
How do you think energy is conserved in this case?
"By pure reasoning, potential energy CAN be created from no energy. All that is needed is the emergence of a force field" Do you agree with this statement?
If you disagree, why?
Some paragraphs of this post were accidentally deleted once when I was editing it, that's why its votes are so low. If you think this post is good, please help increase its positive votes.

"The battery's electrical energy is stored in the metal plate." - no, not really. The battery's electrical energy is stored in the electric field between the plates.

From a certain point of view, the electric charge is stored in the metal plate, and the electric field is generated by the electric charge.

When the ball is present, the battery does no extra work pumping the charge.

If you look at the electric field of the capacitor, you will notice that because of its symmetry, the field lines are all orthogonal to the plane through the center. Moving a charge from the center point parallel to the plates requires no work, as the electric force is always orthogonal to the path with no parallel component. That means we can move a charge from the center away to infinity for zero energy. This shows that the potential energy of the small ball is zero, just as it was before you charged the capacitor.

You are humorous, but your answer is not helpful and what you say is wrong, because the existence of potential energy depends on whether there are conservative forces acting on the ball.

Moving the ball from infinity to the midpoint perpendicular to the field line is just another way to create potential energy from no energy, just as I said.

@Justaphysicsstudent Situation 1: There is no ball in the center. Turning the device on will drain some energy $E_1$ from the battery to create the electric field of the capacitor. Situation 2: There is a ball in the center. Some energy $E_2$ is drained from the battery to establish the electric field.
I have shown above that situation 1 can be transformed into situation 2 with no additional energy being drained from anywhere. Therefore $E_1=E_2$.

I totally agree with what you said. I  think the battery wouldn’t do any extra work too. So, that's not where our disagreement lies.

When you mathematically idealize conservative force fields (and their potential), and think about them as external and indipendent from the system, you might say energy is not conserved. This happens for example when the potential depends explicitly on time as it is in your case, as you imagine to let an electric field emerge to surround the ball.
This is just a mathematical idealization though, because when you consider the WHOLE system energy IS conserved. The field doesn't come about on its own. In your case, it's the work done by the battery that moves charges around to create a difference in potential between the two plates. This energy might come for example from chemical potential energy in the battery.

That energy will be stored in the capacitor, whether there is a ball or not.

So, we gain extra energy with the ball compared to without it.

Let's imagine to charge the plates and then disconnect the battery. The electric potential energy is the same whether there is a ball or not. If you let go the ball, it will accelerate converting that potential energy in kinetic. The total energy will be conserved, but the potential electric energy will decrease due to the ball movement.

The presence of the ball just makes this conversion possible.

As long as the ball cannot touch the metal plate, the charge q in the capacitor remains constant, the capacitance c remains constant, and the voltage v remains constant. So, the electrical energy originally from the battery and stored in the capacitor remains constant. But we have the kinetic energy of the ball.

Making calculations with a ball isn't easy, so let's assume the ball is just a partially charged plate inserted in between the other two. If you compute the variation in energy integrating the squared electric field as the plate moves towards the negative capacitor side, you see that it is negative and proportional to the displacement of the inner plate. In the case of the ball qualitatively happens something similar, moving down the hill of potential energy.

The contribution of the ball to the electric potential is zero at the beginning and then becomes negative.

Of course, when the ball starts moving, it is no longer at the midpoint, and the superposition field changes.

But I believe your calculations will tell you it does not mean energy will be conserved. Moreover, the superposition field is still essentially two fields.

One is a radial electric field, the other is a uniform electric field. They are different.
